# jQuery .find() - Label selector click event versus checkbox change event not consistent IE8

Tags: jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-8, label

I have these two events:

```
$(document).on('change','#trackAll',function() {
    $('#tblTrackPlanFood')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$(document).on('click','#trackAllLbl',function() {
    $('#tblTrackPlanFood')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

The first 'change' event is a checkbox (#trackAll). It works fine in IE8. Checkboxes in the '#tblTrackPlanFood' table are checked/unchecked as expected.

However, the second event 'click' '#trackAllLbl' is on a label. In IE8 it does not work. I can insert an alert() and confirm the selector works fine, but the identical '#tblTrackPlanFood' checkbox code does not work when the label is clicked.

Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: And it works on other browsers?

Comment: My only question is why do you use the click event? Clicking on the label trigger the change event as well...

Comment: The label and checkbox are associated so in IE8, the parent 'select all' checkbox would be checked, but the change even on the parent checkbox doesn't trigger in IE8 like Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE9/10. They would all register the change even and check/uncheck the child checkboxes as expected. I added the click event to attempt to satisfy IE8, by explicitly assigning an event to the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is .prop('checked', this.checked);

this is referring to the label, not the checkbox.  Do this instead:

```
$(document).on('click','#trackAllLbl',function() {
    $('#tblTrackPlanFood')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', $("#trackAll").is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you code is that in the second function, `this` is not the check box, but the label.

You need something like this instead :

```
.prop('checked', document.getElementById('trackAll').checked);
```